# How can I diagnose a Unity crash when running the game on a phone?

Tags: unity, android, debugging

I have a 2D android game that is in beta on Google Play. It has about 100 installations, but no testers. I'm the only developer. Some of the users have reported app crashes, and because they are not developers, they can not help me with a diagnosis.

I think the origin of the problem is the phone not having enough memory to run the app. When I rub the app in a [LG-D213c](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_l50-6546.php) running Android 4.4.2, the game opens, and you can navigate the main screen (the title screen). When I select any stage, the game displays the "loading" screen that runs in the same scene as the main title, and `SceneManager.LoadScene ()` is called with the play scene (battle). Then, the game closes. When I do the same procedure with a [Galaxy S5 neo](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s5_neo-6506.php) (SM-G903M) running Android 6.0.1, the app runs normally.

I have collected a log uaing  Android Monitor. Both of them include the moment of the app crash (the name is com.empresa.aplicacion, but this is not the real name).

This is the profiler capture in both cases.

- LG phone case.

  [image: LG profile]
- Galaxy S5Neo case

  [image: Samsung]

So. I have some questions.

- What is the real origin of the problem? How can I diagnos the issue? I'm not seeing the cause, this is the [filtered Log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2VeuXtUuHwKN3F0bkZlZHNNNzA), and this is the [complete log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2VeuXtUuHwKRVVnQ2dXMnc2X0k).
- How can I control this error from inside Unity? Is there a way to catch exceptions from the Unity core, so that it can generate a report?
- How can I make a diagnosis to the installations that I do not have access to, like a production installation or a client that has the app in their phone?

All of my questions are relative to Unity platform.

Comment: Adding Fabric to your app is the best solution to get automatic crash logs reports

Comment: It appears your asking *multiple questions*, here. While some if them are somewhat relevant, some are not, and should be asked *separately* to limit the *broadness* of your question. For example, the core question appears to specifically ask *how do I implement debugging post-production*, as per your title. But you have also included *how do I implement debug **pre**-production, and the entirely irrelevant *how do I fix this specific error, that I can not identify, because I didn't include debugging*.

Comment: My English is not very good. But my intention is to ask how to detect the error that closes the application suddenly in post-production, for that I try to show what the error is through the images and the links to the logs that I collected in pre-production. I do this because neither in pre nor in post-production I have been able to detect the reason for the error, but a remote installation have the same behaviour of my pre production case, so I assume that the user's error may be the same as mine in pre-production

Answer (score 3):

If you did not manage these in production, you'll probably have a really hard time doing it now. Best way to do these tests would be with a [virtual android device](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html), just get [crash reports](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CrashReport.html) from the devices that are getting the crashes then using the same kind of device with the AVD go into detailed diagnostics for [mobile devices](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileCrashes.html). That's how I would do it and how I'm planning to do it for my game.

Answer (score 0):

i hade errors maybe not like you but it was happening on some devices and not others,
changing the graphics api to gles 2 ,maybe removing 32 bit buffer in player settings solved the problem